# How to query the list in a better way using AngularFireDatabase?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

[image]

```
"@angular/fire": "^5.2.3",
```

I am using AngularFireDatabase to manipulate data in firebase. I need to retrieve and update the table below in Firebase. I am currently doing it in the below method. Is there any way which I can use it to query better? Because, I am downloading the entire table and then uploading it again. I don't want to download the entire list of submissions instead just want to push an object to the submission array directly. Thanks in advance.

```
// Get form submissions for a specific form
getFormSubmissions(key: string) {
    this.userSubmissionsList = this.db.list('/form-submissions', ref => ref.orderByChild('formId').equalTo(key));
    return this.userSubmissionsList;
}

getSingleFormForSubmission(key: string) {
    this.submission = this.db.object('/form-submissions/' + key);
    return this.submission;
}

             
             
this.formService.getFormSubmissions(this.formId).snapshotChanges().subscribe(response => {
     let key = null;
     response.forEach(item => {
       const a: any = item.payload.toJSON();
       key = item.key;
     });
                    
     this.formService.getSingleFormForSubmission(key).valueChanges().subscribe(resp => {
        if (resp.submission === undefined) { resp.submission = []; }
          this.formSubs = resp;
     });
  });
```

Pushing the data be like:

```
this.formSubs.submission.push(data);
this.formService.submitUserValues(this.formSubs);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're storing a JavaScript array in Firebase, which unfortunately means it becomes hard to manipulate. To add an item to an array, you must know how many items already exist in that array, which requires that you first read it.

This is one of the many reasons why the Firebase documentation recommends against using arrays, but instead [uses so-called push IDs to add items to lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data). From that documentation:

> Use the `push()` method to append data to a list in multiuser applications. The `push()` method generates a unique key every time a new child is added to the specified Firebase reference. By using these auto-generated keys for each new element in the list, several clients can add children to the same location at the same time without write conflicts. The unique key generated by `push()` is based on a timestamp, so list items are automatically ordered chronologically.

I also recommend checking out this old-but-still-very-true blog post [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).